# How does Linux know how to execute shell vs machine code?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
./something
```

How does Linux know how to execute this if it's a shell script, or compiled machine code? I understand how the `shebang` works, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [binfmt subsystem of the Linux kernel](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/binfmt/) recognizes various magic numbers at the start of the file and invokes the appropriate loader for it.